# disabling radio buttons by name attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

say I have a bunch of radio buttons in an html form.  How do I find and disable all radio input types with a given `name="?"` value (where ? can be anything I specify)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is simple:

```
$('input[name="name_here"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Replace `name_here` with the name of your radio buttons.

And you can **enable** it back from code using:

```
$('input[name="name_here"]').removeAttr('disabled'');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var name = 'someName';
$('#myForm').find(':radio[name=' + name + ']').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```